# If $a^n-1$ is divisible by $b^n-1$ for all $n$, then $a$ is a power of $b$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b$ be natural numbers not equal to $1$ such that $\frac{a^n-1}{b^n-1}$ is natural for any natural $n$. Prove that $a=b^m$ for some natural $m$.

Comment: I showed that it's enough to show that $b|a$. It's quite easy to do that. But I don't know how to do the other part

Answer (score 1):

for all $b\neq 1,$  just write $$b^{mn}-1=(b^n-1)(1+ b+ b^2+....+b^{mn-n-1})$$ From here, it should be easy to get your answer.

Comment: I know why a=b^m is answer, I don't know about the others

Comment: May be you can write the whole solution? Or may be the plan of it

Comment: If you saying that m is not natural, than your formula isn't right, because geometric series works only for natural m

Comment: Touche. However, your problem is equivalent to finding a natural $k$ satisfying 
$a^n-1= (b^m)^n-1=b^{mn}-1=k(b^n-1)$ for all $ b \neq 1$. Do you agree? 

 
Using the geometric series, we can write, for all natural $m,n$: 

$$b^{mn}-1=(b^n-1)(1+ b+ .....+b^{mn-n})$$  Therefore, by analogy, your $k$ is no other than $(1+ b+ .....+b^{mm-n})$ which exists for all $b \neq 1$.

Comment: I understand why a^n-1=k(b^n-1) for all n. It's just from the post. Where k is different natural number. But I don't really understand why k(b^n-1)=b^{mn}-1. It's just not true

Comment: I really wish we had a thrid person's input in this discussion. I really cannot go on any further with this. Please post your answer when you find it. Good luck.

Comment: Here's a third person input. @NumThcurious you gave a hint that obviously was insufficient for OP to solve the problem. You might edit your answer so that it becomes a complete proof. This is better than adding many comments below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution here http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=4556